# How do I overwrite the first row in a 2D array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

If I have a 4x4 array called M[4][4] that is initialized to all zeroes, how do I change the values of the first row nodes later in the program?

The reason I ask is because when initializing a matrix, one only has to do:

```
int M[4][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

But if I do this elsewhere in the code, it doesn't work.

Do I just have to use a loop to accomplish my goal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: there is a massive difference between 'initialization of variable' and 'assigning to variable'  There are a lot of things that can be done 'enmassie'  when initializing a variable that cannot be done when assigning a value to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Well you don't need a custom function to do that, you can use `memcpy`.

```
double M[2][4] = { {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}, {1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 1.4} };
memcpy(M, (const double[4]){1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 1.4}, sizeof(double)*4);
```

In case you wonder how you can write the second row:

```
double M[2][4] = { {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}, {1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 1.4} };
memcpy(&M[1][0], (const double[4]){1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 1.4}, sizeof(double)*4);
```

Comment: Nice answer! I retracted mine suggesting a function to do it since I think this is much better.